# Are there any objective reasons why it is better to not call functions in Angularjs Views to display data?

Tags: angularjs

To make a long story short, in our application at work, we have a function that creates multiple objects that inherit methods from a prototype.

As such:

```
function MileCounter(totalMilesRan, numOfDaysToRunThem) {
   this.totalMilesRan = totalMilesRan;
   this.numOfDaysToRunThem = numOfDaysToRunThem;
};

MileCounter.prototype.avgMilesPerDay = function() {
   return (this.totalMilesRan/this.numOfDaysToRunThem);
}
```

And then in the view, this is called like this:

```
<div> {{mileObj.avgMilesPerDay()}} </div>
```

The disagreement comes from their belief that the average should be provided to the mileObj in the controller so the average can be called in the view just as they would to get `moneyObj.totalMilesRun` as:

```
<div> {{mileObj.avgMilesPerDay}} </div>
```

Something to keep in mind is that the actual objects in question have many more properties than just two and the number of objects being created is usually in the dozens but could eventually sky rocket into the hundreds or even thousands.

My Coworkers believe that the view should not be concerned at all with calculating data and should only be concerned with displaying it.

My Question: Is there an objective reason why it would be better to add the `avgMilesPerDay` value directly to each object, rather than just calling a prototype method to handle it? It is my understanding that adding a bunch of properties to objects could eventually be a drag on memory when there are enough objects being created, with enough properties on each one, and that having simple prototype methods could help ease that burden.

Comment: The prototype method to me is overkill and not typical AngularJs.  If I was on your team I might object to that.  However, objectively there is little reason for preferring a property over a function when binding to the view.  If this is repeated many times on the page, then there may be a performance argument to be had.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Steve. I do understand what you are saying about a prototype being a bit much. But what about a function that is defined on the controller that does the same thing and using that? Like
`function giveAvg(first, second) { return first/second}` and consuming that in the view like `{{giveAvg(mileObj.totalMilesRan, mileObj.numOfDaysToRunThem)}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advantages of calling a function:

- less memory usage
- more encapsulation: changing the value of `totalMilesRan` or `numOfDaysToRunThem` automatically changes the value of the average

Advantages of adding a field for the average:

- slightly more efficient: the average doesn't need to be computed again and again

I would keep using the function from the view unless you have a performance problem, and have proven that it comes from the function call, and it can't be solved in another way (like one-time binding for example).

Comment: Thanks for responding JB. Why is the adding a field slightly more efficient -- especially if the values are being bound using the one-time binding approach, as you mentioned?

Comment: With one-time binding, there won't be any difference. But with normal binding, every digest loop will have to reevaluate the expression, and thus call the function computing the average, to detect a change and refresh the dom with the potentially new value.

Comment: Plus when not one-time bound , need to be careful what you/anyone else (now or in the future) write inside the bound function. Since they run every digest cycle an expensive method can make the page unresponsive and you could get into [infinite digest issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332674/calling-function-inside-angularjs-goes-in-endless-loop) as well.